# Template classes arma::Col in Rcpp Armadilllo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

Dear fellow programmers,

in order to write a bootstrapped regression version for a seminar at university I tried to implement my R-version into Rcpp (this is for comparison of R to C++/Rcpp). However, I'm stuck with the error messages I receive, since I don't really understand those (the struggle of being new to C++ and especially Armadillo).

Here's the code I'm using. The first function is one I copied from the internet to get proper row-subsets of my matrix (in order to implement a proper non-parametric bootstrap):

```
    #include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::mat testrows(arma::mat x, arma::Col idx) {
  arma::mat xsub;
  xsub = x.rows(idx-1);
  return xsub;
}
```

Furthermore, here's the code I wrote for my actual bootstrap version:

```
   #include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat betaBoot(arma::colvec& y, const arma::mat& X, const int nboot) {
    int n = X.n_rows, k = X.n_cols;
    arma::mat betaHat(k,nboot);
    for(int i = 0; i < nboot; i++){
        Rcpp::NumericVector colId = Rcpp::runif(n, 0, (n-1));
        arma::mat X_boot = testrows(X, colId);
        arma::colvec y_boot = y(colId);
        betaHat.col(i) = arma::solve(X_boot, y_boot);
    }
    return betaHat;
}
```

`betaHat` is a matrix to contain the bootstrapped coefficient-vectors (in each column), the matrix should have dimension k x nboot. `X_boot` (within the loop) should be the bootstrapped data and `y_boot` the corresponding dependent observations. `colId` should be a random index for the bootstrapping procedure. Finally, `betaHat` should be returned.

attached you find a picture of the errors I receive when using sourceCpp.

[image: Error Messages]

Maybe it's something simple I just can't see or maybe the lack of experience, however learning this stuff would be great. So if you could help me with that, that would be great.
Thank you in advance
Erin

Edit: The way my bootstrapped regression function now looks (and works):

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat betaBoot(arma::colvec& y, const arma::mat& X, const int nboot) {
    int n = X.n_rows, k = X.n_cols;
    arma::mat betaHat(k,nboot);
    for(int i = 0; i < nboot; i++){
        arma::uvec colId = arma::randi<arma::uvec>(n, arma::distr_param(0,n-1));
      
        arma::mat X_boot = X.rows(colId);
        arma::colvec y_boot = y(colId);
        betaHat.col(i) = arma::solve(X_boot, y_boot);
    }
    return betaHat;
}
```

Thanks to all the helpful comments I received.

Comment: Froma quick look `testrows` takes a `arma::Col` for the indices but you pass a `Rcpp::NumericVector` in `betaBoot`.  You also seem to be subsetting with a real (random uniform) rather than an integer index (should they be uvec?)

Comment: Good hints! I forgot that runif creates reals. Do you know of something like R's sample(c(1:n), replace=T, size = n)?

Is that first error for template arguments related to wrong passing (what you mentioned about NumericVector -> arma::Col)?
Uvec seems more natural, however I got to admit I did not really understand the posts about vec and uvec I read on the internet.

Comment: Both Rcpp and RcppArmadillo have sample functions

Comment: As a general rule, I recommend starting from the simplest _working_ building blocks. Here you clearly have a problem with `testrows` so I would recommend working on being able to call that to randomly select rows before moving on.

Comment: Re: Dirk's suggestion to start with `testrows()`, I think you should be able to fix that by *not* using `arma::Col`. If you take a look at the *excellent* Armadillo docs [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col), you'll see that that specification would require something like `arma::Col<double>`; you probably want `arma::vec` (which is equivalent to `arma::Col<double>`)

Comment: @ErinSprünken; you could use `arma::uvec idx = arma::randi<arma::uvec>(n,  arma::distr_param(0,n-1));` to randomly sample integers with replacement, inwhich case you would use `arma::uvec` in `testrows` signature (and select rows with `arma::mat xsub = X.rows(idx);`

Comment: Thank you all so much. Indeed I found that I do not need my (stolen) helper function testrows at all, however I also misunderstood the way .rows works (I thought it works like A[n:p,] in R, not like A[c(...),]). Now, I directly implemented the suggested sampling and .rows function. If you write an answer I will definitely accept. So again, thank you all duckmayr, Dirk and @user20650.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments; the function `testrows` takes an `arma::Col` for the indices but an `Rcpp::NumericVector` is passed in `betaBoot`, hence error. You are also subsetting with a real (random uniform) rather than an integer index. `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo` provide `sample` functions which can be used here. (Also from the armadillo help pages should be [uvec](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat)).

You can produce the indices to select rows using `Rcpp`  sugar functions:

```
Rcpp::IntegerVector x = Rcpp::seq(0, n-1);
arma::uvec idx = Rcpp::as<arma::uvec>(Rcpp::sample(x, n, true)) ;
```

Or you can do it directly with [arma::randi](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#randi):

```
arma::uvec idx = arma::randi<arma::uvec>(n,  arma::distr_param(0,n-1));
```

Some code with the second method, omitting `testrows` as "*I found that I do not need my (stolen) helper
function testrows*":

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
        
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat betaBoot( arma::mat X, arma::vec y, int nboot){
  
  int n = X.n_rows,  k = X.n_cols;
  arma::mat betaHat(k, nboot);
  
  for(int i=0; i < nboot; i++){
    arma::uvec idx = arma::randi<arma::uvec>(n,  arma::distr_param(0,n-1));
    arma::mat X_boot = X.rows(idx);
    arma::vec y_boot = y.elem(idx);
    betaHat.col(i) = arma::solve(X_boot, y_boot);
  }  
  return betaHat;
}

/***R
set.seed(1)
n = 25
nc = 2
x = cbind(1, matrix(rnorm(n*nc), nc=nc))
y = rnorm(n)

sim = betaBoot(x, y, 2000)
*/
```